# viewport render not working

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view

When I hit the render viewport shading, it keep displaying the normal viewport. At the beginning of my project it worked perfectly but I stopped using the dual viewport, when I came to use it the second time, somehow it didn't work. Maybe I touched something I shouldn't?

[image: Footage of my problem]

Comment: Try "Ctrl+Alt+B"... just in case you have accidentally defined a render border

Comment: Are you using CPU or GPU compute? What is your graphics card and system specs? Maybe it's a GPU or driver issue.

Comment: This little dot here below the axis is probably a render border https://i.gyazo.com/a9994f4c3788857b7a7318c13aadbd65.png

Comment: @lemon you are probably right, looks like a very small render border making it look as if viewport render is not working at all.

Comment: it may be affecting the light in the scene. do you have an environment on stage?

Answer (score 6):

You may have paused the viewport rendering. Check if the 'pause' button in the viewport menu/header is pressed.

Comment: Even if it was paused it wouldn't show the viewport, it would show a checkerboard image.

Comment: For me, that was totally it. It rendered everything but it just looked like there were no materials nor lights. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem a few days back. You must've accidentally set the render border too small to be visible hence it appears not to be rendering.

You can clear the render border by pressing **CTRL+ALT+B** or you can do it manually by going to the View>View Borders>Clear Render Border